# How to solve this equation with multiple square root terms?

Tags: linear-algebra

$(T^2-512)^{0.5}+(T^2-620)^{0.5}+(T^2-812)^{0.5}+(T^2-972)^{0.5}+(T^2-1100)^{
0.5}=3T$

I first tried to just square each side to get rid of the square roots. But there were more square roots generated than deleted.My friends also solved this equation by using MAPLE software,it seems like it is only way to solve this equation, but i want to solve it manually step by step.Anybody have the idea to solve this equation manually? thanks

thanks

Wayne

Comment: Are there any constraints on T.

Comment: no. By using Maple software, my friend can have the answer: T=36.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $T$ to be an integer we must have all the terms under the radical signs, perfect squares.

Hence $$T^2-512=a^2 \cdots(1)$$

also $$T^2-620=b^2 \cdots(2)$$

$(1)-(2)$

$$a^2-b^2=108=(a+b)(a-b)$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are integers therefore $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ must be integral multiples of $108$. Also the sum of these two multiples must be even for $a$ and $b$ to be an integer.

Solving you will get solutions $(26,28),(12,6)$ . For $(26,28)$ letting, $a=26$ you can calculate $T$, which comes out to be $36$, also this solution satisfies the equation in question. For $(12,6)$ letting $a=12$ gives irrational $T$, as our $T$ is an integer we will neglect this. Hence the answer is $T=36$

Comment: It is nice solution, thanks, but it is based on the assumption that T is integer, what if T is a real number?Is there a deductive way to solve this equation?

Comment: @acoolme you said in the comments that my friend...maple...T=36. So ithought you only wanted integer solutions. Well check on maple if there exists any other solution if there does, then i will carry on, and add my answer with the other solution if i could find one.